# copyTextureToTexture results in horrible aliasing artifacts in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

When I use copyTextureToTexture to copy texture1 with a loaded image to texture2 -a datatexture created with the same dimensions and format, I get strong aliasing artifacts like all GPU filtering is disabled -most of it at least, as anisotropy seems to work partially. I'm  struggling for the last 2-3 days to find a solution, but still I'm not sure if this is a three.js bug, or am I missing something. Any help will be appreciated.
Even a WEBGL solution is welcome, as long as it can work along with three.js.

The following is the full test-code: by clicking on the window you can toggle between the original and the copied texture to compare the artifacts.

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var hx = w / 2;
var hy = h / 2;

var camera, scene, renderer, tog1;
var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, w / h, 10, 25000);
camera.position.z = 20;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color("#f2f7ff");
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight("#eef0ff"));

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight("#ffffff", 2);
light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
scene.add(light);

const myurl = "https://i.imgur.com/UiTMJzv.png";
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture1 = textureLoader.load(myurl, setup);

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  container.focus();
  mouseX = (event.clientX - hx);
  mouseY = (event.clientY - hy);
}

function setup() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(w, h);
  renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var anisomax = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
  texture1.anisotropy = anisomax;
  texture1.needsUpdate = true;

  //create datatexture
  var data = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024 * 3);
  var texture2 = new THREE.DataTexture(data, 1024, 1024, THREE.RGBFormat);
  //texture2.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter; //THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter;//THREE.NearestFilter;//THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter; //THREE.LinearFilter;
  //texture2.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; 
  //texture2.generateMipmaps = true; 
  texture2.anisotropy = anisomax;
  texture2.needsUpdate = true;

  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: "#ffffff",
    map: texture2
  });
  material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(400, 400);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(mesh);

  //copy loaded texture to datatexture
  renderer.copyTextureToTexture(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), texture1, texture2);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

  var inf = document.getElementById("info");
  inf.innerHTML = "Copied Texture to DataTexture</br>--click to toggle--";

  // toggle between texture loaded and coppied
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {

    tog1 = (tog1 === false) ? true : false;

    scene.remove(mesh);
    if (tog1 === true) {
      material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: "#ffffff",
        map: texture2
      });
      material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
      inf.innerHTML = "Copied Texture to DataTexture</br>--click to toggle--";
    } else {
      material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: "#ffffff",
        map: texture1
      });
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
      inf.innerHTML = "Original Texture</br>--click to toggle--";
    }
    scene.add(mesh);
  });

  animate();
} //end setup

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x);
  camera.position.y = 1000;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>copyTextureToTexture test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="info"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: image used in the code]

Comment: Unrelated but what was the setTimeout stuff trying to solve?

Comment: At some point it wouldn't work without that,  but at this later form it doesn't need it, you are right. Thanks for making the snippet work -what was the secret?

Comment: I copied your image to regular imgur to get it to work. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370236/128511

Comment: @user5515 did you ever find a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Hardware antialasing is only applied to the Framebuffer. It's a known limitation of WebGL. You can use antialasing postProcessing to compensate for it and/or or render to higher res intermediate buffers and then downsample them to display resolution after you're done doing your render to texture.

( Edit: Just read more about this and I'm not sure the current exact limitations, so it may need some researching )

Comment: thanks, but I'm copying to another texture in order to use it as any other normal texture, eg loaded to the framebuffer, I'm not talking about "antialias: true" that we put on the webglrenderer -I have even set that to false, as the first texture doesn't need it. 

What doesn't work is the minFilter and magFilter. If I uncomment those lines, and set mipmaping to true, the renderer fades the image instead of switching to another auto-generated mipmap. Also anisotropic works to a much lesser degree. 

It's just byte-copying, I can't believe this is causing so much trouble...

Comment: "eg loaded to the framebuffer," scrap this, I meant to be used like any other texture, linearly blurring while the angle is increased -that doesn't work.

Comment: Is your texture a power of 2 sized?

Comment: Yes, 1024x1024. I've tried several other power of 2 dimensions.