# How can I pass a three.js texture as "WebGLTexture" to WEBGL code?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, textures

I'm trying to pass a three.js texture to gl.texSubImage WEBGL function and I get the following error:

**On Chrome:**

[image: Uncaught TypeError]
[image: line]

**On Firefox:**

[image]

The code follows bellow - the destination texture2 is passed to gl.bindTexture bellow and is not recognized. The source texture1 is a texture loaded with an image.

I have tried: texture2, texture2.image, texture2.image.data,
both with a datatexture and a normal texture loaded with an image as texture2.
Any ideas?

```
var gl = renderer.getContext();
var position = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);

renderer.setTexture2D( texture2, 0 ); 

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2.image.data); //<<< problem

gl.texSubImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
                  0, 
                  position.x, 
                  position.y, 
                  gl.RGB, 
                  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                  texture1.image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at [WebGLRenderer.copyTextureToTexture()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.copyTextureToTexture). It internally uses `texSubImage`. There is also an example that shows the usage of the method:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_partialupdate.html

BTW: Using `image.data` in `bindTexture` does not work since the API call expects a `WebGLTexture` object as second parameter. You can access the raw `WebGLTexture` object of a texture like this.

```
var textureProperties = renderer.properties.get( texture );
console.log( textureProperties.__webglTexture );
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried copyTextureToTexture here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071390/copytexturetotexture-results-in-horrible-aliasing-artifacts-in-three-js

The problem is that after the copy, the destination texture does not behave normally with filtering minFilter and magFilter,  and/or anisotropy works only partially you can see artifacts on the snippet on that post.  So I'm trying the core WEBGL in case there is a three.js bug somewhere, but after your correction it works, but I get the same result. Either the bug is somewhere else on three.js,  or on the WEBGL code.

Comment: You might want to create a reduced test case without `three.js` to see if it's the default behavior of WebGL.